# A question on $dis(x,A)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ and $F = \left\{ {{v^*}Av:v \in {\mathbb{C}^n}:{v^*}v = 1} \right\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$($F$ is compact
 and convex set)

and $S = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{C}:\left\| x \right\| \le \varepsilon } \right\}$.

Why does $F + S = \left\{ {\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}:dis(\lambda ,F) \le \varepsilon } \right\}$?

(where ${dis(\lambda ,F)}$ denotes the distance between $\lambda$ and 
$F$)

Comment: The equality is false, take for example $F = (0, 1)$. Check again if you've made any mistakes while typing the exercise.

Comment: @  Dominik -- Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check both inclusions separately. Use the fact that for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ there is an $x \in F$ so that $d(\lambda, x) = d(\lambda, F)$ [this follows from compactness].

Comment: @ Dominik -- Which compact theorem used in this proof?

Comment: There is no specific theorem, just use that every compact space is sequentially compact.

Comment: @ Dominik -- Please complete proof, this work is not hard for you. Thanks.

Comment: This site is meant to help people with math problems, not solve their homework. The hint is already a huge step toward the solution, now it's time for you to do your part.

Comment: @ Dominik --Thanks, but it is'nt my homework

Comment: @ Dominik -- Please send your Email Address.